# What's this Coffescript use of then?

Tags: syntax, coffeescript, semantics

In Trevor Burnham's book on Coffeescript (p81) he has

```
newcard.save().then =>
    ...
```

Which is not part of a conditional or a switch statement. Is **then** just a joining word for the syntax or does it have a semantic purpose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course ... *It calls the* `newcard.save().then` *function* - thanks @rightfold - which is in the [Angular.js *promises* api](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q). Not immediately obvious out of context of that api which BTW is nicely explained [here](http://andyshora.com/promises-angularjs-explained-as-cartoon.html).

Answer (score 1):

It calls the `newcard.save().then` function, passing a function. It is equivalent to the following ECMAScript 6 code:

```
newcard.save().then(() => { ... })
```